# Custom Visual Studio Context Menus

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, t4, visual-studio-addins

I want to use T4 templates to automatically create some code but I want to add a user input box (to ask for a name, for example) similar to the MVC3 "Add View" / "Add Controller" dialog when you right click on a specific folder. Is this possible with pure T4 templates or is it going to result in a writing a VS plugin DLL? If it involves writing a DLL can I just plop that into the projects reference and use it per-project or does it have to be registered individually on each machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out. I probably should of tried this first. Just add the required imports to your T4 template:

```
<#@ assembly name="System.Windows.Forms.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Drawing.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Windows.Forms" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Drawing" #>
```

and then create a form programmatically with a label, input box and button. On DialogResult.OK (for example) just read the input value and do what you need with it. Works perfectly :-)